# How do I print to stdout during stylus compilation

Tags: stylus

I have a Rails 3 application and would like to print to stdout while running

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I would like to do this because my assets compile locally, but throw a syntax error when I deploy to heroku. The error output is not very helpful. I have narrowed it down to one file that is just a bunch of imports of other stylus files.

How can I print to stdout? I put

```
warn("at the point")
```

in the stylus file, but it throws an error about an unexpected symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Stylus uses node. So you should be able to use `console.info("something")`